# Entity Framework many-to-many relationship values not saved in database

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I've set up a many-to-many relationship using Code First and the Entity Framework 5.  The join table has been created but the field data does not save to the database.

The workers are being added to the Project object successfully and the db.SaveChanges() method executes without error but when the GET request for the /Project/Edit/x action is called again the Workers list property is empty.

How do I make this work so the connected Worker data is persisted and retrieved along with the Project object in the GET request after it has been 'saved' via the POST?

**Controller: ProjectController.vb**

POST: /Project/Create/x

```
    For i As Integer = LBound(strWorkerIds) To UBound(strWorkerIds)
        Dim workerId As Integer
        If Integer.TryParse(Trim(strWorkerIds(i)), workerId) Then
            Dim worker As Worker = db.Workers.Find(workerId)
            If Not worker Is Nothing Then
                project.Workers.Add(worker)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    If ModelState.IsValid Then
        db.Projects.Add(project)
        db.SaveChanges() ' The project is saved along with the correct project.Workers list
        Return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home")
    End If
```

POST: /Project/Edit/x

```
    For i As Integer = LBound(strWorkerIds) To UBound(strWorkerIds)
        Dim workerId As Integer
        If Integer.TryParse(Trim(strWorkerIds(i)), workerId) Then
            Dim worker As Worker = db.Workers.Find(workerId)
            If Not worker Is Nothing Then
                project.Workers.Add(worker)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    If ModelState.IsValid Then
        db.Entry(project).State = EntityState.Modified
        db.SaveChanges() 'The changes to project.Workers list are NOT being saved?
        Return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home")
    End If
```

**Model: Project.vb**

```
Public Class Project

    Public Sub New()
        Me.Workers = New List(Of Worker)()
    End Sub

    Public Property ProjectID As Integer
    'other properties...
    Public Overridable Property Workers As ICollection(Of Worker)

End Class
```

**Model: Worker.vb**

```
Public Class Worker

    Public Sub New()
        Me.Projects = New List(Of Project)()
    End Sub

    Public Property WorkerID As Integer
    'other properties...
    Public Overridable Property Projects As ICollection(Of Project)

End Class
```

**DB Context: ProjectLogContext.vb**

```
Imports System.Data.Entity
Imports System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions

Public Class ProjectLogContext

    Inherits DbContext

    Public Property Projects As DbSet(Of Project)
    Public Property Workers As DbSet(Of Worker)

    Protected Overrides Sub OnModelCreating(modelBuilder As DbModelBuilder)
        MyBase.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder)

        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove(Of PluralizingTableNameConvention)()

        modelBuilder.Entity(Of Worker)().HasMany(Function(w) w.Projects) _
            .WithMany(Function(p) p.Workers) _
            .Map(Function(x) x.MapLeftKey("WorkerID").MapRightKey("ProjectID") _
                 .ToTable("WorkerProject"))

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to StackOverflow.  Just a suggestion - can you replicate this in a smaller set of code, e.g. without the MVC controller code which is not necessarily relevant to your question?  There is a lot of code here, and this is an EF question rather than an MVC one if I'm correct?

Comment: Thanks @iandotkelly, I've cut the code down to show the important parts.  It seems the EF doesnt know that the project.Workers list has been modified and/or it is not updating this in the database.  How can I make it update the project.Workers list in the db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the state to `Modified` for the parent entity won't have any effect on relationships in a many-to-many association. To achieve a correct update you must load the current entity graph (parent including its children) from the database and then either *add* a child if its ID is in your ID list or *remove* the child if its ID is *not* in the ID list. EF's change tracking will follow those modifications of the loaded graph and generate the necessary INSERT and DELETE statements to update the link table. It could look like this in your Edit POST action (in C#):

```
var projectInDb = db.Projects.Include(p => p.Workers)
    .SingleOrDefault(p => p.ProjectID == project.ProjectID);

if (projectInDb != null)
{
    // Convert string list to integer list
    var workerIds = new List<int>();
    foreach (string strWorkerId in strWorkerIds)
    {
        int workerId;
        if (int.TryParse(strWorkerId.Trim(), out workerId))
            workerIds.Add(workerId);
    }

    // Update scalar properties of the project
    db.Entry(projectInDb).CurrentValues.SetValues(project);

    // Remove workers
    foreach (var workerInDb in projectInDb.Workers.ToList())
    {
        if (!workerIds.Contains(workerInDb.WorkerID))
            projectInDb.Workers.Remove(workerInDb);
    }

    // Add workers
    foreach (int workerId in workerIds)
    {
        if (!projectInDb.Workers.Any(w => w.WorkerID == workerId))
        {
            var workerInDb = db.Workers.Find(workerId);
            if (workerInDb != null)
                projectInDb.Workers.Add(workerInDb);
        }
    }

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Slauma, as you and @jd3155490 have rightly pointed out I was not "Including" the child Workers list, I simply assumed that EF would track this automatically.  Also I note that you have not used the modified state in your code, would it work without this `_db.Entry(project).State = EntityState.Modified;` ?

Comment: @Rob144: Yes, it does. `db.Entry(projectInDb).CurrentValues...` takes care of updating the project properties. (I had to use `projectInDb` instead of `project` however, I've fixed that.) jd31...'s code won't work btw because using `Include` only in the GET request is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are 'including' workers attached to a project while getting project in GET: /Project/Edit/x action. I replicated your issue in C# and I am able to get the list of Workers attached to a project if I include workers in the lambda expression in GET: /Project/Edit/x action. Here is the ProjectController code fyr.

```
readonly ProjectLogContext _db = new ProjectLogContext();
// GET: /Project/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = _db.Projects.ToList();
        return View(model);
    }

    //GET: /Project/Create/x
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //POST: /Project/Create/x
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Project project)
    {
        string[] strWorkerIds = { "26", "27", "28" };

        for (var i = strWorkerIds.GetLowerBound(0); i <= strWorkerIds.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
        {
            int workerId;
            if (!int.TryParse(strWorkerIds[i], out workerId)) continue;
            var worker = _db.Workers.Find(workerId);
            if (worker != null)
            {
                project.Workers.Add(worker);
            }
        }

        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View();
        _db.Projects.Add(project);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Project");
    }


    //GET: /Project/Create/x
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var query = _db.Projects.Include(p => p.Workers).Single(p => p.ProjectId == id);
        return View(query);
    }

    //POST: /Project/Create/x
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Project project)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View();
        _db.Entry(project).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Project");
    }
```